# How to show options depend on area google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm doing some modification for Taxi android app , I want to know how to show **Car Type** depend on  the area on the map or city. - **(coordinate)**

For example :
In New York i have these options (Mini , SUV , miniVan, Limousine) with special price for each one.

But
in NeW jersey I have just two option (Mini , Suv) with different price (Not Like New york for example).

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on co ordinates you can find the city

```
`      try {
            Geocoder geocoder;
            String city=null;
            List<Address> yourAddresses;
            geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            yourAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(yourLatitude, yourLongitude, 1);


        final String yourAddress = yourAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        if (yourAddresses != null && yourAddresses.size() > 0) {
            android.location.Address address = yourAddresses.get(0);
            @SuppressWarnings("MismatchedQueryAndUpdateOfStringBuilder") StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            }
            city = address.getLocality();
            Log.d("city", "onCreate: "+city);
        }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`
```